# Error Installing MS office in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: wine

While I am installing ms office 10 or 13 using wine it says the following:

```
Unhandled exception: 0xc06d007e in 32-bit code (0x7b83ae0b).
Register dump:
 CS:0023 SS:002b DS:002b ES:002b FS:0063 GS:006b
 EIP:7b83ae0b ESP:0a6cd3f8 EBP:0a6cd45c EFLAGS:00000287(   - --  I S - -P-C)
 EAX:7b826449 EBX:7b8b0000 ECX:0a6cd480 EDX:0a6cd41c
 ESI:00dd2428 EDI:00000000
Stack dump:
0x0a6cd3f8:  0a6cd4d0 00000004 000a0009 c06d007e
0x0a6cd408:  00000000 00000000 7b83ae0b 00000001
0x0a6cd418:  0a6cd480 7b8589db 7ffd0c00 00000000
0x0a6cd428:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
0x0a6cd438:  00000000 7ffd0c00 00000000 7b8b0000
0x0a6cd448:  0a6cd468 7b858b2e 00dd24c0 00000000
Backtrace:
=>0 0x7b83ae0b in kernel32 (+0x2ae0b) (0x0a6cd45c)
  1 0x00dc93bb in msi7bec.tmp (+0x493ba) (0x0a6cd4c4)
  2 0x00dc78d8 in msi7bec.tmp (+0x478d7) (0x0a6cd704)
  3 0x00dc28cd in msi7bec.tmp (+0x428cc) (0x0a6cd940)
  4 0x00d9caf8 in msi7bec.tmp (+0x1caf7) (0x0a6ce83c)
  5 0x7def9393 CUSTOMPROC_wrapper+0xa() in msi (0x0a6ce848)
  6 0x7def9671 CUSTOMPROC_wrapper+0x2e8() in msi (0x0a6ce9a8)
  7 0x7def994f CUSTOMPROC_wrapper+0x5c6() in msi (0x0a6ce9f8)
  8 0x7bc7f84c call_thread_func_wrapper+0xb() in ntdll (0x0a6cea08)
  9 0x7bc7f89b call_thread_func+0x44() in ntdll (0x0a6ceae8)
  10 0x7bc7f82a in ntdll (+0x6f829) (0x0a6ceb08)
  11 0x7bc871f3 in ntdll (+0x771f2) (0x0a6cf368)
  12 0xf75c5d78 start_thread+0xd7() in libpthread.so.0 (0x0a6cf468)
  13 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  14 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  15 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  16 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  17 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  18 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  19 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  20 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  21 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  22 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  23 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  24 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  25 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  26 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  27 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  28 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  29 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  30 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  31 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  32 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  33 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  34 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  35 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  36 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  37 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  38 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  39 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  40 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  41 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  42 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  43 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  44 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  45 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  46 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  47 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  48 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  49 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  50 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  51 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  52 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  53 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  54 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  55 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  56 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  57 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  58 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  59 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  60 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  61 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  62 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  63 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  64 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  65 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  66 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  67 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  68 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  69 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  70 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  71 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  72 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  73 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  74 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  75 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  76 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  77 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  78 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  79 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  80 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  81 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  82 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  83 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  84 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  85 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  86 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  87 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  88 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  89 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  90 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  91 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  92 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  93 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  94 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  95 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  96 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  97 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  98 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  99 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  100 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  101 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  102 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  103 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  104 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  105 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  106 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  107 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  108 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  109 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  110 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  111 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  112 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  113 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  114 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  115 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  116 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  117 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  118 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  119 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  120 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  121 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  122 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  123 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  124 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  125 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  126 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  127 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  128 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  129 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  130 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  131 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  132 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  133 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  134 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  135 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  136 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  137 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  138 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  139 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  140 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  141 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  142 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  143 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  144 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  145 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  146 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  147 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  148 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  149 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  150 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  151 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  152 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  153 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  154 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  155 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  156 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  157 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  158 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  159 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  160 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  161 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  162 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  163 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  164 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  165 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  166 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  167 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  168 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  169 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  170 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  171 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  172 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  173 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  174 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  175 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  176 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  177 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  178 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  179 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  180 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  181 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  182 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  183 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  184 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  185 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  186 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  187 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  188 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  189 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  190 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  191 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  192 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  193 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  194 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  195 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  196 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  197 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  198 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  199 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  200 0xf74fc3de __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
0x7b83ae0b: subl    $4,%esp
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (149 modules)
PE    840000-  86f000   Deferred        osetupui
PE    ba0000-  ba7000   Deferred        msi7c0d.tmp
PE    d40000-  d51000   Deferred        msi7bb6.tmp
PE    d80000-  ddd000   Export          msi7bec.tmp
PE    de0000-  df8000   Deferred        msi83ed.tmp
PE    e00000-  e0a000   Deferred        msi83f8.tmp
PE    f40000- 1072000   Deferred        pidgenx
PE   1440000- 145a000   Deferred        msi958a.tmp
PE   9e80000- 9edb000   Deferred        msi889c.tmp
PE   9ee0000- 9f0a000   Deferred        msi9130.tmp
PE  10000000-10593000   Deferred        osetup
PE  2e000000-2e119000   Deferred        setup
PE  41110000-41155000   Deferred        msi7bd6.tmp
PE  504a0000-504c7000   Deferred        msi9112.tmp
PE  504d0000-504f0000   Deferred        msi8b04.tmp
ELF 7b800000-7ba44000   Dwarf           kernel32<elf>
  \-PE  7b810000-7ba44000   \               kernel32
ELF 7bab6000-7bb00000   Deferred        libdbus-1.so.3
ELF 7bc00000-7bce4000   Dwarf           ntdll<elf>
  \-PE  7bc10000-7bce4000   \               ntdll
ELF 7be0f000-7be32000   Deferred        localspl<elf>
  \-PE  7be10000-7be32000   \               localspl
ELF 7be32000-7bf00000   Deferred        libkrb5.so.3
ELF 7bf00000-7bf04000   Deferred        <wine-loader>
ELF 7bf09000-7bf25000   Deferred        spoolss<elf>
  \-PE  7bf10000-7bf25000   \               spoolss
ELF 7bf25000-7bf3c000   Deferred        libresolv.so.2
ELF 7bf3c000-7bf64000   Deferred        libk5crypto.so.3
ELF 7bf64000-7bfa1000   Deferred        libgssapi_krb5.so.2
ELF 7bfa1000-7c000000   Deferred        libcups.so.2
ELF 7c208000-7c2aa000   Deferred        msvcrt<elf>
  \-PE  7c220000-7c2aa000   \               msvcrt
ELF 7c2aa000-7c400000   Deferred        libxml2.so.2
ELF 7c40c000-7c415000   Deferred        librt.so.1
ELF 7c415000-7c427000   Deferred        libavahi-client.so.3
ELF 7c427000-7c468000   Deferred        winspool<elf>
  \-PE  7c430000-7c468000   \               winspool
ELF 7c468000-7c485000   Deferred        libgcc_s.so.1
ELF 7c485000-7c4c2000   Deferred        libxslt.so.1
ELF 7c4c2000-7c4e9000   Deferred        liblzma.so.5
ELF 7c4e9000-7c59e000   Deferred        msxml3<elf>
  \-PE  7c4f0000-7c59e000   \               msxml3
ELF 7c59e000-7c5cd000   Deferred        msxml6<elf>
  \-PE  7c5a0000-7c5cd000   \               msxml6
ELF 7d0e1000-7d0ea000   Deferred        libkrb5support.so.0
ELF 7d0ea000-7d0f8000   Deferred        libavahi-common.so.3
ELF 7d5b5000-7d5b9000   Deferred        libkeyutils.so.1
ELF 7d5b9000-7d5be000   Deferred        libcom_err.so.2
ELF 7d5d6000-7d63e000   Deferred        riched20<elf>
  \-PE  7d5e0000-7d63e000   \               riched20
ELF 7d63e000-7d672000   Deferred        hhctrl<elf>
  \-PE  7d640000-7d672000   \               hhctrl
ELF 7d672000-7d696000   Deferred        hlink<elf>
  \-PE  7d680000-7d696000   \               hlink
ELF 7d696000-7d6b6000   Deferred        oleacc<elf>
  \-PE  7d6a0000-7d6b6000   \               oleacc
ELF 7d6b6000-7d6fa000   Deferred        rsaenh<elf>
  \-PE  7d6c0000-7d6fa000   \               rsaenh
ELF 7d6fa000-7d715000   Deferred        imagehlp<elf>
  \-PE  7d700000-7d715000   \               imagehlp
ELF 7d72d000-7d764000   Deferred        uxtheme<elf>
  \-PE  7d730000-7d764000   \               uxtheme
ELF 7d764000-7d76b000   Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
ELF 7d76b000-7d776000   Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
ELF 7d7f6000-7d81e000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF 7d81e000-7d857000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF 7d857000-7d867000   Deferred        libxi.so.6
ELF 7d867000-7d872000   Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
ELF 7d872000-7d87c000   Deferred        libxrender.so.1
ELF 7d87c000-7d882000   Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF 7d882000-7d8a6000   Deferred        imm32<elf>
  \-PE  7d890000-7d8a6000   \               imm32
ELF 7d8a6000-7d8ad000   Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
ELF 7d8ad000-7d8cf000   Deferred        libxcb.so.1
ELF 7d8cf000-7d8d5000   Deferred        libuuid.so.1
ELF 7d8d5000-7d8ef000   Deferred        libice.so.6
ELF 7d8ef000-7da26000   Deferred        libx11.so.6
ELF 7da26000-7da38000   Deferred        libxext.so.6
ELF 7da38000-7da41000   Deferred        libsm.so.6
ELF 7da41000-7daf2000   Deferred        winex11<elf>
  \-PE  7da50000-7daf2000   \               winex11
ELF 7daf2000-7db8d000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF 7dba5000-7dbb9000   Deferred        libp11-kit.so.0
ELF 7dbb9000-7dbcb000   Deferred        libtasn1.so.3
ELF 7dbcb000-7dc4f000   Deferred        libgcrypt.so.11
ELF 7dc4f000-7dd14000   Deferred        libgnutls.so.26
ELF 7dd14000-7dd38000   Deferred        cabinet<elf>
  \-PE  7dd20000-7dd38000   \               cabinet
ELF 7dd38000-7dd61000   Deferred        mpr<elf>
  \-PE  7dd40000-7dd61000   \               mpr
ELF 7dd61000-7dd7a000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF 7dd7b000-7dd7f000   Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
ELF 7dd7f000-7dd92000   Deferred        gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so
ELF 7dd92000-7de0c000   Deferred        wininet<elf>
  \-PE  7dda0000-7de0c000   \               wininet
ELF 7de0c000-7deb9000   Deferred        urlmon<elf>
  \-PE  7de20000-7deb9000   \               urlmon
ELF 7deb9000-7dfdb000   Dwarf           msi<elf>
  \-PE  7dec0000-7dfdb000   \               msi
ELF 7dfdb000-7e04b000   Deferred        dbghelp<elf>
  \-PE  7dfe0000-7e04b000   \               dbghelp
ELF 7e04b000-7e121000   Deferred        crypt32<elf>
  \-PE  7e050000-7e121000   \               crypt32
ELF 7e121000-7e15b000   Deferred        wintrust<elf>
  \-PE  7e130000-7e15b000   \               wintrust
ELF 7e15b000-7e27a000   Deferred        comctl32<elf>
  \-PE  7e160000-7e27a000   \               comctl32
ELF 7e27a000-7e2f0000   Deferred        shlwapi<elf>
  \-PE  7e290000-7e2f0000   \               shlwapi
ELF 7e2f0000-7e52e000   Deferred        shell32<elf>
  \-PE  7e300000-7e52e000   \               shell32
ELF 7e52e000-7e673000   Deferred        oleaut32<elf>
  \-PE  7e540000-7e673000   \               oleaut32
ELF 7e673000-7e754000   Deferred        gdi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e680000-7e754000   \               gdi32
ELF 7e754000-7e8c4000   Deferred        user32<elf>
  \-PE  7e770000-7e8c4000   \               user32
ELF 7e8c4000-7ea26000   Deferred        ole32<elf>
  \-PE  7e8e0000-7ea26000   \               ole32
ELF 7ea26000-7eab0000   Deferred        rpcrt4<elf>
  \-PE  7ea30000-7eab0000   \               rpcrt4
ELF 7eab0000-7eae4000   Deferred        ws2_32<elf>
  \-PE  7eac0000-7eae4000   \               ws2_32
ELF 7eae4000-7eb56000   Deferred        advapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7eaf0000-7eb56000   \               advapi32
ELF 7eb56000-7eb7b000   Deferred        iphlpapi<elf>
  \-PE  7eb60000-7eb7b000   \               iphlpapi
ELF 7eb7b000-7ebaa000   Deferred        netapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7eb80000-7ebaa000   \               netapi32
ELF 7ebaa000-7ebdf000   Deferred        secur32<elf>
  \-PE  7ebb0000-7ebdf000   \               secur32
ELF 7ebdf000-7ebfa000   Deferred        version<elf>
  \-PE  7ebe0000-7ebfa000   \               version
ELF 7ebfa000-7ec07000   Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF 7ec07000-7ec13000   Deferred        libnss_nis.so.2
ELF 7ec13000-7ec2c000   Deferred        libnsl.so.1
ELF 7ec2c000-7ec35000   Deferred        libnss_compat.so.2
ELF 7efa5000-7efe8000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF 7efe8000-7efec000   Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
ELF 7efec000-7f000000   Deferred        psapi<elf>
  \-PE  7eff0000-7f000000   \               psapi
ELF f7401000-f7405000   Deferred        libxau.so.6
ELF f7406000-f740b000   Deferred        libdl.so.2
ELF f740b000-f75be000   Dwarf           libc.so.6
ELF f75bf000-f75da000   Dwarf           libpthread.so.0
ELF f75da000-f75df000   Deferred        libgpg-error.so.0
ELF f75f2000-f7736000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF f7738000-f775a000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
ELF f775a000-f775b000   Deferred        [vdso].so
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
0000000e services.exe
    0000005b    0
    0000005c    0
    00000059    0
    0000002e    0
    0000001f    0
    00000015    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
00000012 winedevice.exe
    0000001d    0
    0000001a    0
    00000014    0
    00000013    0
0000001b plugplay.exe
    00000021    0
    0000001e    0
    0000001c    0
00000022 explorer.exe
    00000023    0
0000002a (D) C:\users\birendra\Desktop\OFFICE 2010\setup.exe
    0000005d    0 <==
    0000002f    0
    0000002b    0
00000042 OSE.EXE
    00000045    0
    00000047    0
    0000002d    0
    00000036    0
    00000040    0
    00000017    0
    00000018    0
    00000034    0
System information:
    Wine build: wine-1.4.1
    Platform: i386 (WOW64)
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 3.8.0-19-generic
```

Anybody give me suggestion how to fix the problem to install it.

Comment: What version of MS Office? Have you tried using PlayOnLinux?

Comment: Are trying to install 32bit version or 64bit version of office?

Comment: PlayOnLinux with the install scripts they provide has been the only way I was able to install ms office

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar error when running PlayOnLinux. Also got errors about Direct3D when running as script.

I used the script [stored here](https://pastebin.com/xz1VPD9u) and [desribed here](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/3ukrfh/microsoft_office_2013_on_linux_using_playonlinux/). I got errors about direct3d incompatible graphics card. I installed wine 2.5 and changed the corresponding line in the script.

Go to *tools/'manage wine versions'* and add wine 2.5.

Go to configure and a create a new wine 2.5 virtual drive called Office2013

Go to configure and choose Office2013. Edit registry.

In HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wine add a key `Direct3D`. It will show up like a folder. In the folder add a new dword called `MaxGLVersion` with the value `30002`.

Some have also suggested to install *dxfullsetup* and *msxml6*

Answer (score 0):

First of all, give up installing Office 2013, since it has a 'Garbage' rating on [appdb](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=26323).
My advice to you is to install 2010 (32bit).

I see you are running an outdated version of wine. It should install correctly with wine1.5 (or 1.6r3). You can do this by adding the wine ppa:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install wine1.5

Then install wine-mono by running:

> sudo apt-get install wine-mono0.0.8

Then, install it from a clean wine prefix by running:

> WINEPREFIX=~/.officewine wine setup.exe

You can run it afterwards by running:

> WINEPREFIX=~/.officewine wine ~/.officewine/drive_c/Program\ Files/Microsoft\ Office/Office10/winword.exe

If all else fails you can always try PlayOnLinux or run it from a virtual machine or (my favorite option) try [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org). :-)