# Wine msiexec.exe encounter serious error

Tags: software-installation, wine, winetricks, microsoft-office

recently I had make the changes from Windows to Linux, and since then I have learnt new things everyday from making fine adjustment to my liking and troubleshooting some of the problem encountered.

However I had encounter a problem when I tried to install Microsoft Office 2010 with wine 6.0.1, and I encountered the mentioned problem "msiexec.exe encounter serious error"

I had tried using a couple of tutorial and to no avail and all resulted in the same error.
Had tried to install with default prefix, tried create wineprefix with winearch=win32, had done the winetricks to add msxml6 to the library, tried updated the mono and gecko to the latest version available, non are working.

below are the error message that I had encountered, appreciate anyone can give me the pointer or solution to this problem. Thanks.

```
    Unhandled exception: C++ exception(object = 0x014fdb40, type = 0x1004d798) in 32-bit code (0x7b00fd36).
Register dump:
 CS:0023 SS:002b DS:002b ES:002b FS:0063 GS:006b
 EIP:7b00fd36 ESP:014fd964 EBP:014fd9d8 EFLAGS:00000246(   - --  I  Z- -P- )
 EAX:014fd970 EBX:014fdb40 ECX:00000008 EDX:014fda08
 ESI:e06d7363 EDI:014fdc4c
Stack dump:
0x014fd964:  000000e4 014fda38 00000042 e06d7363
0x014fd974:  00000001 00000000 7b00fd36 00000003
0x014fd984:  19930520 014fdb40 1004d798 00000100
0x014fd994:  0000001b 00000000 014fda20 0000065b
0x014fd9a4:  014fda34 00000000 00000000 014fd9d0
0x014fd9b4:  10025981 014fda38 00000100 ffffffff
Backtrace:
=>0 0x7b00fd36 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in kernelbase (0x014fd9d8)
  1 0x10025a4e in msi3b99.tmp (+0x25a4d) (0x014fda14)
  2 0x1003d7cb in msi3b99.tmp (+0x3d7ca) (0x014fdc78)
  3 0x1003b845 in msi3b99.tmp (+0x3b844) (0x014fe2ac)
  4 0x1003b8f9 in msi3b99.tmp (+0x3b8f8) (0x014fe340)
  5 0x100109b6 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in msi3b99.tmp (0x014ff768)
  6 0x650af59c EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in msi (0x014ff778)
  7 0x650b257d EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in msi (0x014ffee8)
  8 0x00401383 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in msiexec (0x014fff28)
  9 0x7b62e280 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in kernel32 (0x014fff48)
  10 0x7bc5bb87 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in ntdll (0x014fff5c)
  11 0x7bc5bde0 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in ntdll (0x014fffec)
0x7b00fd36 EntryPoint+0xffffffff in kernelbase: subl    $4,%esp
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (38 modules)
PE    400000-  440000   Dwarf           msiexec
PE    640000-  bc1000   Deferred        gdi32
PE    bd0000-  fb7000   Deferred        oleaut32
PE  10000000-1005d000   Export          msi3b99.tmp
PE  61740000-61828000   Deferred        advapi32
PE  61940000-61b40000   Deferred        wininet
PE  62e00000-62e45000   Deferred        odbccp32
PE  62fc0000-631f2000   Deferred        rpcrt4
PE  63480000-6349c000   Deferred        version
PE  637c0000-63a73000   Deferred        urlmon
PE  63bc0000-63c02000   Deferred        shcore
PE  64a40000-64b5e000   Deferred        shlwapi
PE  65080000-656a2000   Dwarf           msi
PE  658c0000-65901000   Deferred        sxs
PE  66240000-6627e000   Deferred        bcrypt
PE  68500000-6864b000   Deferred        combase
PE  68700000-6878e000   Deferred        uxtheme
PE  6a400000-6a884000   Deferred        ole32
PE  6bc00000-6bca1000   Deferred        sechost
PE  6bcc0000-6be9c000   Deferred        setupapi
PE  6cc40000-6d0c2000   Deferred        comctl32
PE  6d580000-6d5e2000   Deferred        cabinet
PE  6db40000-6db72000   Deferred        imagehlp
PE  6e8c0000-6eb63000   Deferred        crypt32
PE  6ed00000-6f392000   Deferred        user32
PE  6f4c0000-6f571000   Deferred        wintrust
PE  6fa80000-6fcca000   Deferred        dbghelp
PE  70940000-70997000   Deferred        mpr
PE  70b40000-70df3000   Deferred        ucrtbase
PE  710c0000-710ee000   Deferred        mspatcha
PE  71200000-71248000   Deferred        imm32
PE  7b000000-7b30c000   Dwarf           kernelbase
PE  7b600000-7b928000   Dwarf           kernel32
PE  7bc00000-7bedf000   Dwarf           ntdll
PE  7cf30000-7cf53000   Deferred        msxml3
PE  7d820000-7e0f7000   Deferred        shell32
PE  7e680000-7e684000   Deferred        winex11
PE  7e940000-7e944000   Deferred        ws2_32
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
00000020 setup.exe
    00000024    0
    00000148    0
    000001a4    0
    00000374    0
    000004cc    0
    0000052c    0
00000038 services.exe
    0000003c    0
    00000040    0
    0000004c    0
    00000070    0
    00000088    0
    000000a0    0
    000000b0    0
    000000d4    0
    000000e8    0
    0000015c    0
    000003dc    0
00000044 winedevice.exe
    00000048    0
    00000054    0
    00000058    0
    0000005c    0
00000060 plugplay.exe
    00000064    0
    00000074    0
    00000078    0
    0000007c    0
    000000b8    0
00000068 explorer.exe
    0000006c    0
    00000110    0
    00000114    0
00000080 svchost.exe
    00000084    0
    0000008c    0
    00000090    0
    00000094    0
    00000108    0
    0000010c    0
    00000420    0
00000098 winedevice.exe
    0000009c    0
    000000a8    0
    000000ac    0
    000000b4    0
    000000c0    0
    000000c4    0
000000cc svchost.exe
    000000d0    0
    000000d8    0
    000000dc    0
000000e0 rpcss.exe
    000000e4    0
    000000ec    0
    000000f0    0
    000000f4    0
    000000f8    0
    00000118    0
0000011c conhost.exe
    00000120    0
00000154 OSE.EXE
    00000158    0
    00000164    0
    00000168    0
    0000016c    0
    00000184    0
    00000188    0
    000004b0    0
    000004ac    0
000003d8 OSPPSVC.EXE
    000003e0    0
    000003fc    0
    00000408    0
    0000041c    0
    00000414    0
    00000410    0
    00000428    0
000004c4 (D) C:\windows\syswow64\msiexec.exe
    000004bc    0
    00000544    0 <==
    0000054c    0
System information:
    Wine build: wine-6.0.1
    Platform: i386 (WOW64)
    Version: Windows 10
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 5.11.0-38-generic
```

To add more information to the problem, below are the message before the error occurred.

```
058c:err:ole:com_get_class_object class {807573e5-5146-11d5-a672-00b0d022e945} not registered
058c:err:ole:com_get_class_object no class object {807573e5-5146-11d5-a672-00b0d022e945} could be created for context 0x1
058c:fixme:msxml:dom_pi_get_attributes created dummy map for <?xml ?>
058c:err:ole:com_get_class_object class {807573e5-5146-11d5-a672-00b0d022e945} not registered
058c:err:ole:com_get_class_object no class object {807573e5-5146-11d5-a672-00b0d022e945} could be created for context 0x1
058c:fixme:msxml:dom_pi_get_attributes created dummy map for <?xml ?>
058c:err:ole:com_get_class_object class {807573e5-5146-11d5-a672-00b0d022e945} not registered
058c:err:ole:com_get_class_object no class object {807573e5-5146-11d5-a672-00b0d022e945} could be created for context 0x1
058c:fixme:msxml:dom_pi_get_attributes created dummy map for <?xml ?>
0590:fixme:msi:MsiGetLastErrorRecord 
0590:fixme:msi:MsiGetLastErrorRecord 
wine: Unhandled exception 0xe06d7363 in thread 590 at address 7B00FD36 (thread 0590), starting debugger...
```

Comment: @MadMike Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately that did not answer my question. As I had used the same method once but not working.

Comment: I consider this the wrong place to ask. Memory issuses in WINE seems more something for wineHQ https://forum.winehq.org/

Comment: Hi @Rinzwind, So this was the memory issues rather than the installation process that has went wrong?

Comment: Well it could be that that lead to it :) See for instance this old one https://askubuntu.com/questions/312820/error-installing-ms-office-in-ubuntu-13-04

Comment: You say you tried the same method. Did you also try POL (Playonlinux)?. You mention all the other tools POL is by far the easiest. If you tried POL you should go into detail what you tried and what exactly didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I install Microsoft Office? If so, how?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156296/can-i-install-microsoft-office-if-so-how). Install PlayOnLinux and use its wizard to install MS Office. It is proven reproducible method.

Comment: @MadMike Hi, sorry for not stating it clearly, I did not use the POL for the installation, but was using WineHQ with the same library as mentioned, the different with the mentioned method was the wine version. Rather than the wine version 3.0 or 3.8 but I was using wine version 6.0.1. However just now I give POL wizard a tried, and it will install the Office 2010. However knowing that POL will work and not the winehq itself make me want to know what is going on and what has been done wrong on my part.

Comment: @N0rbert, yes POL will install without problem. But I wish to drill down on what has went wrong with non POL method.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance provided by everyone involved. POL method will install the Office 2010 successfully. However I wish to understand the reason why the non POL method failed with version 6.0.1. And I will post the question to WineHQ forum for further discussion. Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: I can totally relate to that feeling of wanting to be in control and of why stuff-works-now and also why-stuff-didn't-work-before. What is upping the diffuclty here is previous steps can have effects on the latest tries and helping other people will need a broad understanding around the domain to know what needs to be checked. You will need to document both installtions where cleanly so other can help working out why one thing worked and the other didn't. Also you will need to start an new question and post that documentation.

Comment: You have to open https://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-801-Microsoft_Office_2010.html and then carefully analyze *Source Code* spoiler part.